# Subclassing UITapGestureRecognizer in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

I want to subclass [`UITapGestureRecognizer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITapGestureRecognizer_Class/) as `TapRecognizer` so that navigation between pages within my app are handled in a standardised way:

1. Dragging a `UITapGestureRecognizer` onto any navigational elements in the storyboard, setting their class as `TapRecognizer`, and referencing them within the View Controller as an IBOutlet (`@IBOutlet var heroTapRecognizer: TapRecognizer!`)
2. Initialising them like so:

   ```
   self.heroTapRecognizer = TapRecognizer.init(pageId: 1, pageType: PageType.CategoryPage)
   ```

Then in **TapRecognizer.swift**:

```
class TapRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer {
    var pageId:Int!
    var pageType:PageType!

    convenience init(pageId: Int, pageType: PageType) {
        self.init()
        self.pageId = pageId
        self.pageType = pageType
        self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(TapRecognizer.handleTap(_:)))
    }

    func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        if sender.state == .Ended {
            print("Handle navigation based on pageId + pageType")
        }
    }
}
```

But the above isn't working. I'm new to Swift and have only previously used `UITapGestureRecognizer`'s programmatically.

Note: User interaction **is** enabled on the `UIView` that the recogniser is associated with.

Comment: @TroyT I can only init with `init(target:action:)` and as self isn't initialised at this point I can't set the target property accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Dragging a UITapGestureRecognizer onto any navigational elements in the storyboard, setting their class as TapRecognizer, and referencing them within the View Controller as an IBOutlet

Okay, but then your `init` will never be called. If you want something special to happen, implement `awakeFromNib`.

Alternatively, implement `init(coder:)`. For some reason this is not documented, but it is the initializer that is actually called.

Comment: @RyanBrodie I suggest you undelete your answer rather than trying to put words in my mouth, if you know what I mean :)